# Create Responsive Tabs using Bootstrap (They should get stacked automatically on smaller screens)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create responsive tabs which get stacked automatically using bootstrap.
The code for my navs is -

```
<div>
    <ul id="tabslist_navs" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#">Normal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hover</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Selected</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

I need them to get converted to stacked tabs when viewed on small screens.
Right now it just moves the tabs into multiple likes which looks ugly.
I want something like the navbar collapse but without the button to activate the collapse.

Answer (score 39):

This should work:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
    .nav-tabs > li {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that works... but is there any other way <other than extra media query> to do that?

Comment: According to Bootstrap's documentation there isn't, but if you're using `bootstrap-responsive.css` you could add the code to the file to have it all more organized (line 887)

Answer (score 18):

With BootStrap version **3**, you have everything stacked in a clean vertical way for Extra Small Device by adding 4 CSS classes. [BootStrap and Tab](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modifying-bootstrap-tab-control-for-extra-small-device) does not render greatly as you have noticed. The code below can do the job by removing all background and border.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .nav-tabs > li {
        float:none;
        border:1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a{
        border:none;
    }
    .nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus,
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus
     {
        background:none;
        border:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. But you should use `border:1px solid transparent` instead to prevent the links from jittering on mouseover because the border is being removed and added.

Comment: Slight improvements:`@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .nav-tabs > li {
        float: none;
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
    .nav-tabs > li.active {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .nav > li > a:hover,
    .nav > li > a:focus,
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
    .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
        background: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
}`

Answer (score 4):

If you find that 480 doesn't do it (I have long tab titles), you can always change your max-width. I used:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) { 
 .nav-tabs > li {
    float:none;
 }
}
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an extra answer. But seeing your RP, I see why you did this.

Comment: My RP? I'm happy to change to a comment if I can.. Here to learn mainly and was happy I could actually contribute for once! XD

Comment: RP = Reputation Points. It's good to see people contributing!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SCSS or LESS support, you should use the proper media query vars:

In SCSS:

```
  @media (max-width: $screen-md-min) {
    .nav-tabs > li {
      float:none;
    }
  }
```

In Less:

```
  @media (max-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .nav-tabs > li {
      float:none;
    }
  }
```

Check http://getbootstrap.com/css/ for details regarding the possible vars.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        .nav-tabs > li {
            float:none;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }
        .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }
        .nav-tabs > li  > a {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
            border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
            border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }
        .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
            border-color: #dddddd;
        }
    }
```

This one is more simple and good-looking.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here still leave much to be desired, in my opinion. Here is a solution that builds on the earlier solutions but uses CSS flexbox. The tabs stay side by side when possible, wrap to multiple lines only when needed, and still fill the width of the screen, with the horizontal space distributed evenly. It looks clean and balanced, and scales well to handle longer tabs or larger numbers of tabs. It also resolves some border and border-radius issues of the other solutions.

SCSS:

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-max) {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-right: 1px;
    > li {
      flex: auto;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid $nav-tabs-border-color;
      margin-right: -1px;
      > a {
        margin: 0;
      }
      &.active {
        background: $gray-lighter;
        > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
          border: none;
          background: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, plain CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-right: 1px;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li {
    flex: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-right: -1px;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li.active {
    background: #eee;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a,
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    border: none;
    background: none;
  }
}
```