# hide and show Drop Down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This menu is for admin page. Below is the example how the menu will display from My SQL database.
[image]

Menu will get increased when admin add in database. So when menu increases (when it hits the particular width) icon should display in right and while clicking it should show as dropdown menu like below in the image.

[image]

Any jquery or Javascript available for this type of function?

Comment: yep: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/

Comment: have look on this

1)  http://www.bootply.com/xvAx7qs67v 
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888598/create-responsive-tabs-using-bootstrap-they-should-get-stacked-automatically-on
this my helpful for you